# How to get items from string array in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

```
// strings.xml

<string-array name="list">
    <item>Istinye Park</item>
    <item>Kanyon Istanbul</item>
    <item>Akmerkez</item>
    <item>Forum Istanbul</item>
    <item>Istanbul Cevahir</item>
    <item>Metrocity</item>
    <item>Istanbul Sapphire</item>
</string-array>
```

I need to access specific item of string-array from java. I can access to string with `R.string.str` and to array with `R.array.list`. But need something like `R.array.list[1]` to access specific item of array.

Comment: You have there code. Which code?

Comment: `String[] shopping = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shopping);` For your reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: I have there just string-array and I know how to access to array but I don't know how to access to some specific item (from java). For ex: I need to access to "Istinye Park" with single code line, How I can get it?

Comment: `String istinyePark = shopping[0];`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can load it via the resources with `getStringArray`, then just manipulate it like a standard array.

```
Resources res = getResources(); //assuming in an activity for example, otherwise you can provide a context.
String[] shoppingItems = res.getStringArray(R.array.shopping);
String istanbul = shoppingItems[1]; //Kanyon Istanbul
```

Answer (score 4):

for the whole string array:

```
    String[] myStringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
```

for single item from the string-array resource

```
    String myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names)[numberOfItem];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yourcontext.getResources().getStringArray(YOUR_ARRAY_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shopping);`